# Toggle a repeated class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="profile_photo">
   <img style="float:left;margin-right:7px;" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/53566ac91a169b353a78b329bdd35c95?s=50&d=identicon" class="profile_img" alt="{username}"/>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="status-#">
   <div class="message">
    <span class="username">{username} Debugr Rocks!
   </div>
   <div class="info">24-oct-2010, 14:05 GMT · <a href="#" class="toggle_comment" title="Comment">Comment (5)</a> · <a href="#" title="Flag" class="toggle_flag">Flag</a> · Via <a href="#" title="Twitter">Twitter</a>
</div>
   <div class="comment_container">
    <div class="profile_photo">
     <img style="float:left;margin-right:7px;" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/53566ac91a169b353a78b329bdd35c95?s=32&d=identicon" class="profile_img" alt="{username}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_message">
     <span class="username"><a href="#" title="{username}">{username}</a></span> Debugr Rocks! XD
    </div>
    <div class="comment_info">24-oct-2010</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="profile_photo">
   <img style="float:left;margin-right:7px;" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/53566ac91a169b353a78b329bdd35c95?s=50&d=identicon" class="profile_img" alt="{username}"/>
  </div>
```

That is **repeated two or more times**. What I want to do, is to when I click the "Comments (5)" link, the class "comment_container" appears, but **only the one in the same "container" class.**

It's this possible?

Comment: I won't even consider helping unless you indent your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to go up to the `.container` then [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to look inside it, like this:

```
$(".toggle_comment").click(function() { 
    $(this).closest(".container").find(".comment_container").show();
});
```

[You can try it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/LZX3X/), if you're curious about finding other things relative to `this` [here's a full list of the Tree Traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

---

As an aside, there's an error in your HTML that needs correcting, this:

```
<span class="username">{username} Debugr Rocks! </div>
```

Should be:

```
<span class="username">{username} Debugr Rocks! </span>
```

Comment: But, is it possible to start hided, and then when someone clicks that, shows the .comment_container?

Comment: @Francesc - absolutely, just add `.comment_container { display: none; }` to your CSS, like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BcTx3/ (I used `.toggle()` for the demo, `.show()` works the same for *only* showing if that's what you're after).